# Is it possible to swap the result of two std::tie calls

Tags: c++, templates, std, stdtuple

I have been trying for a while to find a standard compliant way to get something like this to compile:

```cpp
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;

std::swap(std::tie(a, b), std::tie(c, d));
```

(The use case is more complicated (related to zip iterators...) but this is the core of the problem).

The reason this fails to compile is `std::swap` expects lvalue references, however because `std::tie` returns a `std::tuple<T&...>`, you can have it swap the elements it is indirectly referring to (even when `std::tuple` is an rvalue).

One way to get this to work is to add an overload for `std::swap` to the `std` namespace:

```cpp
namespace std {
  template<typename... Refs>
  void swap(std::tuple<Refs&...> lhs, std::tuple<Refs&...> rhs) {
    lhs.swap(rhs);
  }
}
```

However, I know this is not standard compliant...

Another alternative is to add a type that is essentially a wrapper around `std::tuple`, and add an overload for `swap` in your own namespace. `swap` can then be found via argument dependent lookup (ADL) when that type is used from another standard algorithm like `std::sort`.

```cpp
template<typename... Ts>
struct tuple_wrapper {
  std::tuple<Ts...> ts_;
  tuple_wrapper(Ts... ts) : ts_(ts...) {}
  // implementation...
};
```

The problem with that is trying to write a transparent wrapper around `std::tuple` is proving to be tricky to say the least  (if I try and use that type with `std::sort` I often get pages of compile errors and writing a new complicated type to mimic `std::tuple` doesn't seem ideal...).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this in a simple(ish) way with a standard compliant solution? Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you!

**Update**

Ideally I'd like to get this to work in C++ 17, thank you 康桓瑋 for pointing out this does actually work in C++ 23 due to [P2321](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2321r2.html).

**Update 2**

Here's a snippet from the class this example is based on...

```cpp
template<typename... InputIts>
class zip_iterator {
  std::tuple<InputIts...> its_;

public:
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using value_type =
      std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIts>::value_type...>;
    using difference_type = std::common_type_t<
      typename std::iterator_traits<InputIts>::difference_type...>;
    using pointer =
      std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIts>::pointer...>;
    using reference =
      std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIts>::reference...>;

    zip_iterator(InputIts... its) : its_(its...) {}

    reference operator*() {
      return std::apply([](auto&... its) { return std::tie(*its...); }, its_);
    }

    // ... rest of implementation, mostly other operators
};
```

The problem I've been having is with `reference`, and how it interacts with `std::swap` and then `std::sort`.

Note this implementation is inspired by this post for reference - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231352/c17-zip-iterator-compatible-with-stdsort. I was just looking to see if I could create a slightly simpler implementation if at all possible

---

**Update**: It turned out I stumbled into a topic that was much more complicated than I first anticipated to do with 'Proxy Iterators'. To understand the full complexity at play here please do read these four articles from Eric Niebler:

- https://ericniebler.com/2015/01/28/to-be-or-not-to-be-an-iterator
- https://ericniebler.com/2015/02/03/iterators-plus-plus-part-1
- https://ericniebler.com/2015/02/13/iterators-plus-plus-part-2
- https://ericniebler.com/2015/03/03/iterators-plus-plus-part-3

Long story short is doing this properly (so move only types are handled correctly and more...) requires changes to the standard library.

It seems like the most sensible advice is wait for C++23 or use ranges-v3 like I should have done

Comment: Your code [complies fine in C++23](https://godbolt.org/z/YEEqE8G5T) thanks to [P2321](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2321r2.html).

Comment: Even though you said that the use case feels more complicated, it still feels like an XY-problem. If you are swapping in a certain line of code... Why not assign in the correct order `std::tie( c, d )` and `std::tie( a, b )` on that specific line of code?

Comment: my not just write your own swap function? https://godbolt.org/z/eve618G48

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far! I should have mentioned I'm trying to get this to compile in C++ 17, interesting to know this is fixed in C++23.

Comment: I unfortunately can't write my own swap with a custom name as I need it to be found via ADL in other contexts (like std::sort)

Comment: I'll try and add more context but essentially this is a reduction of the main problem I was trying to solve which was a zip iterator to allow multiple ranges to be zipped and then sorted. The issue is for the new custom iterator, the reference type is that std::tuple<T&> thing, and std::sort really doesn't like that unless I have that overload I mentioned (or use a custom type)

Comment: @康桓瑋 Here is paragraph in P2231 addressing this: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2321r2.html#proxy-reference-changes and here the overload of std::swap introduced in C++23: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/swap2

Comment: Do you have one user-type inside the tuple?

Comment: Thanks @joergbrech for the link to the exact part from C++ 23, that is super interesting (and bummer it got missed before ).

Comment: To answer @Jarod42's question, in my little toy example I am trying to wrap a std::tuple, and the user type could really be anything. I'll add a quick snippet in the questions shortly...

Comment: @Jarod42 Does it matter? AFAIK, it is no longer allowed to add function template specializations to `std`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have a solution I'm at least reasonably happy with .

Big thank you to 康桓瑋, André, Alan Birtles, joergbrech and Jarod42 for their comments that helped steer me in the right direction (in particular 康桓瑋 who referenced [P2321](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2321r2.html) and the C++ 23 solution).

**Stop reading now if you're using C++ 23. This problem is fixed and just works TM**.

If you're still stuck using C++ 20 or C++ 17, read on...

To work around this problem (and to avoid needing to add an overload to the `std` namespace) you can add a wrapper type around `std::tuple`.

Below are a couple of options that are almost certainly incomplete (and might fail under some usages) but for now they've worked for me. I'll be writing a bunch of tests and benchmarks for this soon and will link to that here as well for future reference, hopefully with a few more fixes/improvements.

There are two possible options, I haven't decided yet which is preferable (needs more investigation/testing/profiling) but I'll include them both here for now.

### Option 1

Create a `tuple_wrapper` type and include an implicit constructor for `tuple_wrapper` to convert from `std::tuple`.

```cpp
namespace thh {
template <typename... Ts>
struct tuple_wrapper {
    std::tuple<Ts...> ts_;
    tuple_wrapper(Ts... ts) : ts_(ts...) {}
    // implicit conversion from std::tuple
    tuple_wrapper(std::tuple<Ts...> tup) : ts_(std::move(tup)) {}
};

// swap overload for tuple_wrapper of references
template <typename... Refs>
void swap(tuple_wrapper<Refs&...> lhs, tuple_wrapper<Refs&...> rhs) {
    lhs.ts_.swap(rhs.ts_);
}
} // namespace thh

// usage
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;
using std::swap;
swap(thh::tuple_wrapper(std::tie(a, b)),
     thh::tuple_wrapper(std::tie(c, d)));
```

[Compiler Explorer demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z7WsnccWs)

### Option 2

Create a `tuple_wrapper` type and provide our own implementation of `std::tie` (see reference implementation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

```cpp
namespace thh {
template <typename... Ts>
struct tuple_wrapper {
    std::tuple<Ts...> ts_;
    tuple_wrapper(Ts... ts) : ts_(ts...) {}
};

// our own version of tie that returns a tuple_wrapper
template <typename... Args>
constexpr tuple_wrapper<Args&...> tie(Args&... args) noexcept {
    return {args...};
}

// swap overload for tuple_wrapper of references
template <typename... Refs>
void swap(tuple_wrapper<Refs&...> lhs, tuple_wrapper<Refs&...> rhs) {
    lhs.ts_.swap(rhs.ts_);
}
}  // namespace thh

// usage
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;
using std::swap;
swap(thh::tie(a, b), thh::tie(c, d));
```

[Compiler Explorer demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/84hzcez9f)

The first one is perhaps better? I'm not sure yet if there's any reason to prefer one over the other (convention/compatibility/performance?). I'm going to do some more tests and will report back if I find a better answer.

The above hopefully answers my initial question. The slightly more complex use case I was alluding to gets a bit more complicated (more operators are required to play nice with `std::sort`).

My current (likely woefully incomplete implementation) looks like this:

```cpp
namespace thh {
  template<typename... Ts>
  struct tuple_wrapper {
    std::tuple<Ts...> ts_;
    tuple_wrapper(Ts... ts) : ts_(ts...) {}
    tuple_wrapper(std::tuple<Ts...> tup) : ts_(std::move(tup)) {}
    template<typename... UTypes>
    tuple_wrapper& operator=(tuple_wrapper<UTypes...>&& other) {
      ts_ = std::move(other).ts_;
      return *this;
    }
    template<typename... UTypes>
    tuple_wrapper& operator=(const tuple_wrapper<UTypes...>& other) {
      ts_ = other.ts_;
      return *this;
    }
    template<typename... UTypes>
    tuple_wrapper(tuple_wrapper<UTypes...>&& other) {
      ts_ = std::move(other).ts_;
    }
    template<typename... UTypes>
    tuple_wrapper(const tuple_wrapper<UTypes...>& other) {
      ts_ = other.ts_;
    }
    template<size_t I>
    auto& get() {
      return std::get<I>(ts_);
    }
    template<size_t I>
    const auto& get() const {
      return std::get<I>(ts_);
    }
    bool operator==(const tuple_wrapper& rhs) const { return ts_ == rhs.ts_; }
    bool operator!=(const tuple_wrapper& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }
  };
} // namespace thh
```

I am not going to paste all the code here but you can find a full implementation of the `zip` iterator below:

[Compiler Explorer demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o6E5PxW7f)

This implementation was heavily inspired by [this question and Zip implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231352/c17-zip-iterator-compatible-with-stdsort) from [DarioP](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/37449/dariop). See the [ZipIterator](https://github.com/dpellegr/ZipIterator) GitHub project for an alternate implementation.

Also for some additional context, what prompted this was looking into more efficient ways to sort multiple ranges without the need to allocate additional memory. The approach I was using before is described in this blog post - [Sorting Indirectly](https://tomhultonharrop.com/c++/sorting/2023/08/19/sorting-indirectly.html).

Thanks again and I hope this was useful for someone else too - I'll add a link to my repo with this code once it's all tidied up and tested!